# Best Python podcasts?

Tags: python, podcast

Could any one suggest good Python-related podcasts out there, it could be anything about Python or its eco-system (like django, pylons, etc).

Comment: I think this question becomes ever more significant now because there is no any python podcasts left alive.

The last one was http://radiofreepython.com/episodes/ but with the last show in may of 2013

Comment: April 2015 we launched Talk Python To Me at http://www.talkpythontome.com/ precisely because all the other podcasts seemed to have shut down. Hope you like it.

Comment: I had the same question and couldn’t find a good and updated list of Python developer or Python programming podcasts online. So I started my own list: https://dbader.org/blog/ultimate-list-of-python-podcasts (Contact me if you'd like to get on the list or if you think I missed a podcast. Thanks!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Google Code University](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/index.html) (several languages there)
[Python Podcasts](http://advocacy.python.org/podcasts/)
[Python Learning Foundation](http://www.awaretek.com/python/index.html)
[Python411 on PodcastAlley.com](http://www.podcastalley.com/podcast_details.php?pod_id=5786)

Comment: 3 of your links are broken, you might want to fix that :)

Comment: @Jakkra - Yeah, I'll try to find them again. Hard to keep an eye on every answer given in the last 5 years :-) Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

I didn't think much of Python411 - the episode I downloaded primarily consisted of the host talking about how he was planning on writing a GAE site.

[This Week in Django](http://thisweekindjango.com/) as pointed out by Geo is (or possibly was) a good Python podcast. Obviously, as it's focused on Django development there is a lot of Djangoisms discussed however there's also a lot of general Python knowledge shared as well. TWID is currently going through a revamp, keep an eye on [@djangodose](http://twitter.com/djangodose) for updates.

Answer (score 3):

[The Changelog](http://thechangelog.com/) (read the blog, listen to the podcast, it is very good) has some Python material, for instance:

- http://thechangelog.com/post/1174335646/episode-0-3-6-django-dash
- http://thechangelog.com/post/1087757312/episode-0-3-4-mongrel2-guitar-and-more-with-zed-shaw
- http://thechangelog.com/post/610697985/episode-0-2-4-facebook-open-source-projects-tornado-hip

There has been a few IronPython-related shows on some of the .NET podcasts:

- http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=177
- http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=429
- http://www.craigmurphy.com/blog/?p=708

Answer (score 2):

[thisweekindjango](http://thisweekindjango.com/)

Answer (score 2):

- Some Pycon talks are available on [blip.tv](http://blip.tv/search?q=pycon)
- Pycon podcasts are available [here](http://advocacy.python.org/podcasts/pycon.rss)